# Member Type Template Specialization

Tags: c++, templates, using

I have a class template `S1` with two integer arguments:

```
template <int A, int B> struct S1 { };
```

I have another class template `S2` with one integer argument. In `S2` there is a type template `My_S1` that specializes `S1`. It works fine when `S1` is instantiated through a specialization of `S2` in `main`:

```
template<int A> struct S2 {
  template<int B>
  using My_S1 = S1<A, B>;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  using S1_a = S2<0>::My_S1<0>;
}
```

---

But if I try to do this in a third class template as below, I get an error when compiling. Full code:

```
template<int A, int B>
struct S1 { } ;

template<int A>
struct S2 {
  template<int B>
  using My_S1 = S1<A, B>;
};

template<int A, int B>
struct S3 {
  using My_S1 = typename S2<A>::My_S1<B>; // I get an error on this line
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  using S1_a = S1<0, 0>;         // works fine, of course
  using S1_b = S2<0>::My_S1<0>;  // works fine
  using S1_c = S3<2,1>::My_S1;   // ?
  return 0;
}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
using My_S1 = typename S2<A>::My_S1<B>;
                                   ^
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler explicitly that `S2<A>::My_S1` is a template:

```
//                            vvvvvvvv-- here
using My_S1 = typename S2<A>::template My_S1<B>;
```